# finding column number of a csv file in r

Tags: r

I have a big csv file. I would like to know, how many columns does it have?

I am loading the file like this:

```
k<-read.csv("/home/.../BB/test25000m_60hz.csv",header=FALSE)
```

thank you for your helps

Comment: read the first line and count the number of column separators

Comment: `ncol(k)` or `dim(k)` for rows,columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most useful strategy for looking at a file structure is

```
table(count.fields(file=file_name,  ___ ) )
```

In the space for *_*, one puts the parameters for  comment.char , sep,and quote.

Answer (score 1):

If you're strictly looking for how many columns a csv contains, and not about manipulating/analyzing/processing the data, the following code should work:

```
length(read.csv("/home/.../BB/test25000m_60hz.csv",
       header=FALSE))
```

Comment: It doesn't hurt to [add more than code to an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274)!